# [Solved] rtabmap with external odometry (Realsense T265)

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-lunar, realsense-camera, rtabmap-odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
ROS version: Lunar
RTAB-Map: 0.17.6
Cameras: Realsense D435 and T265

I'm starting both cameras with this launch command: `roslaunch realsense2_camera rs_d400_and_t265.launch align_depth:=true` (see [rs_d400_and_t265.launch](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros/blob/development/realsense2_camera/launch/rs_d400_and_t265.launch))

The map frame looks like [this](https://pasteboard.co/IUaeEdY.jpg).

When I start rtabmap without external odometry and have visual odometry (uses the image/depth data provided by the D435), it seems to be working fine: `roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start" depth_topic:=/d400/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw rgb_topic:=/d400/color/image_raw camera_info_topic:=/d400/color/camera_info approx_sync:=false frame_id:=t265_odom_frame`

This starts rtabmap and shows the 3D image as expected.

But when I include external odometry from the T265 then I get an empty rtabmap window where nothing is displayed: `roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start" depth_topic:=/d400/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw rgb_topic:=/d400/color/image_raw camera_info_topic:=/d400/color/camera_info approx_sync:=false frame_id:=t265_odom_frame visual_odometry:=false odom_topic:=/t265/odom/sample`

There's also a warning message on stdout which only happens if I include external odometry:

```
[ WARN] [1581412938.063114202]: /rtabmap/rtabmapviz: Did not receive data since 5 seconds! Make sure the input topics are published ("$ rostopic hz my_topic") and the timestamps in their header are set. If topics are coming from different computers, make sure the clocks of the computers are synchronized ("ntpdate"). Parameter "approx_sync" is false, which means that input topics should have all the exact timestamp for the callback to be called.
/rtabmap/rtabmapviz subscribed to (exact sync):
   /t265/odom/sample,
   /d400/color/image_raw,
   /d400/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw,
   /d400/color/camera_info,
   /rtabmap/odom_info
[ WARN] [1581412938.420139502]: /rtabmap/rtabmap: Did not receive data since 5 seconds! Make sure the input topics are published ("$ rostopic hz my_topic") and the timestamps in their header are set. If topics are coming from different computers, make sure the clocks of the computers are synchronized ("ntpdate"). Parameter "approx_sync" is false, which means that input topics should have all the exact timestamp for the callback to be called.
/rtabmap/rtabmap subscribed to (exact sync):
   /t265/odom/sample,
   /d400/color/image_raw,
   /d400/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw,
   /d400/color/camera_info,
   /rtabmap/odom_info
```

Odometry data is coming through fine as the command `rostopic echo /t265/odom/sample` shows:

```
header: 
  seq: 2186
  stamp: 
    secs: 1581324175
    nsecs: 245380878
  frame_id: "t265_odom_frame"
child_frame_id: "t265_pose_frame"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -0.000204464944545
      y: -7.67098099459e-05
      z: -0.000421570963226
    orientation: 
      x: -0.00432776007801
      y: 0.0274204164743
      z: 0.000154268200276
      w: 0.999614655972
  covariance: [0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.00355814174321
      y: -0.00205399848924
      z: 0.000575806943033
    angular: 
      x: 0.00179574472786
      y: 0.00634724180174
      z: 0.00126657017099
  covariance: [0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001]
```

Any ideas what else I can check? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343793/%5Bsolved%5D-rtabmap-with-external-odometry-(realsense-t265)/) by [dschnabel](https://answers.ros.org/users/51661/dschnabel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2020-02-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bn059](https://answers.ros.org/users/51804/bn059/) on 2020-02-15**:
Same issue with realsense D415 and T265 on Melodic! Did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros/issues/1078#issuecomment-586669208 for solution.

Quote for posterity:

> Hi @RealSenseCustomerSupport
>
> thank you for those threads. The occupancy mapping was a great starting point. Once I got that working, I went back to playing around with [rs_rtabmap.launch](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros/blob/development/realsense2_camera/launch/rs_rtabmap.launch). I then [disabled re-localization](https://github.com/m-pilia/realsense-ros/commit/6521e3f97382fa49d0abc73ab04fefebebe83264) of the T265:
>
> ```
> <rosparam>
>         /t265/tracking_module/enable_relocalization: false
> </rosparam>
> ```
>
> Next I set `subscribe_odom_info` to false as per [this thread](https://answers.ros.org/question/316737/rtabmap-with-tango-ros-streamer-rtabmap-did-not-receive-data-since-5-seconds/?answer=316938#post-id-316938) in rtabmap.launch at several places: [here](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/launch/rtabmap.launch#L264-L265) and [here](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/launch/rtabmap.launch#L318-L319). This change requires restarting the `roscore`.
>
> When I launch rtabmap via `roslaunch realsense2_camera rs_rtabmap.launch` I have to wait long enough for both cameras (D435 and T265) to start up. Once both cameras have started, I can finally use rtabmap to build a map. This is working great for me now.
>
> Appreciate your help with this. Closing as solved.

---

Originally posted by [dschnabel](https://answers.ros.org/users/51661/dschnabel/) with karma: 103 on 2020-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1